# Narrator. Is there an alternative DialogContent?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, narrator

I have many Custom and UserControl in my app.

For *DialogContent* the Narrator reads **only inside the control** using key combination "Caps Lock" + "Arrow", 
but for the *CustomControl* and *UserControl* the narrator read all automation tree (**outside control**).

How can I make *CustomControl* with characteristics *DialogContent* (reads only inside the control)?

Is there an alternative DialogContent?

[image: Example using ContentDialog + Narrator + Key combination "CapsLock" + "Arrow"]

Comment: Can you give some image to help us to know?

Comment: @lindexi yes, i edited description this task.

Comment: @lindexi blue frame indicates the position of the narrator when moving with the keys combination ("CapsLock" + "Arrow").

Comment: @lindexi, do you have ideas?

Comment: I dont think I can make this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XAML attached properties in the [AutomationProperties Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties). In your case, you can set `AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"` on any pieces of your custom control to prevent Narrator from accessing those pieces.

> The main scenario for using this property is to deliberately omit certain controls in a template from the UI Automation views, because they don't meaningfully contribute to the accessibility view of the entire control. For example, if you look at the default control templates, you'll often see this XAML attribute applied to either a ContentPresenter or TextBlock that's part of a control composition, setting AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView to "Raw". If this hadn't been done, either the document view or control view would see these parts as distinct UI Automation elements and not as unimportant control parts. The "raw "view of a UI Automation tree is typically only consumed by automation tools or special modes in some of the more advanced assistive technology products. (Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties.accessibilityview))

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have very big UI Automation tree and setting "AutomationProperties.Accessibility View" to "Raw" for all elements very difficult. Also this case very dangerous for skipping bugs.                                       So I'm looking for a default control with CocntentControl properties or an example of writing a custom control with these properties.

Comment: ContentDialogs show up in a different visual tree root than everything,  which is why Narrator only "reads inside" the control. Anything inside the dialog that is not read has their AccessibilityView set to Raw and the controls automation peer handles any other accessibility behaviors. If you want a custom dialog, you can create a custom control that derives from ContentDialog, and that would have all the same properties. If you want your custom control to be inline in the main tree of your app, you need to set everything to raw or you might be able to write a custom automation peer.

Comment: David Grochocki, thanks, now I understand how to create an automation tree for the content dialog and user control.